# What is the shortest search pattern that matches nowhere?

Tags: pattern, match, matchadd

This is mostly a curiosity-driven question.

I can't think of anything shorter than `x\@=y`, which tries to match `x` and `y` at the same position. A slightly longer, but probably more self-explaining pattern is `\_.\@!`, which reads more or less as *"a thing that matches everything, should not match"*.

---

For those who wonder why I need a pattern matching nothing and nowhere, I need one to get a match ID for `matchadd`, so that I can then update that very match over and over, reusing always the same id. Basically, I call this

```
let g:id = matchadd('Search', 'x\@=y', 10, -1)
```

when loading a plugin, and later on everytime I need to updated the matches I've created I can do

```
call matchdelete(g:id)
call matchadd('Search', 'some pattern', 10, g:id)
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need to get a global matchid for something that does not match

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, `call matchadd(_, _, _, id)` errors if `id` is already taken, so I have to `call matchdelete(id)` first, but if I don't have one, it errors.

Comment: So why do you only call `matchdelete()` if you have an existing match-`id`?

Comment: .... Because `matchadd` fails if I call it with an existing `id`.

Comment: .. so if you don't have an existing id, use `-1` and you will get a new fresh id.

Comment: Yes, but I want to update that very match over time. To do so I have to delete and redo it everytime. No? Indeed `-1` is what I pass the first time, to get a new fresh id. But then I want to use it over and over.

Comment: I still don't understand. If you don't have a matchid yet, don't call matchdelete(). then create a new match and remember the matchid. then you have a match-id > 0 . So you next time you can `matchdelete()` it.

Comment: I have to updated the matches over and over, because the pattern changes over time (the pattern is roughly the `\w\+` being typed). So I have to delete the matches and make them again.

Comment: Yes, but you have to do it anyhow, not? Why do you need an initial match id?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146971/discussion-between-enlico-and-christian-brabandt).

Comment: `x\&y` also tries to match x and y in the same position, but is a character shorter than `x\@=y`, and, for me, is also slightly easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've gotten a [better answer in the comments](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63897187#63897187), but for curiosity's sake, note that unless you add atoms [specifically to avoid this](https://vimhelp.org/usr_27.txt.html#27.8), patterns will generally only match in a single line.

So there are a large number of two character patterns that don't match anywhere:

- `x^` An `x` followed by the start of a line,
- `$.` The end of a line followed by any character,
- `$^` The end of a line followed by the start of the line,
- etc.

Comment: I didn't even try that, thinking `^` and `$` would be literal if not used at the beginning and end of the pattern! Apparently, I was confusing with SED: `sed 's/^c/X/' <<< 'ci^ao'` gives `Xi^ao`, but `sed 's/i^/X/' <<< 'ci^ao'` gives `cXao`.